# how to save data from medium editor using javascript/jquery and php

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a blog and I want to add medium editor in taking my content and for saving. I have been searching the internet and I have tried on my own using JavaScript but its not given me anything at all.

HTML

```
<div class="editable" id="articles" data-field-id="content">
<button id="publish_article"></button>
```

JS

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable',{
                                placeholder:{
                                  text:'Type Your Article',
                                  hideOnClick:true
                                })
$('#publish_article').click(function(){
      $('.editable').bind('input propertychange, function(){
        var x=$('#article'+$(this).attr("data-field-id")).val($(this).html());});});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume you've instantiated the editor in the same way you did in your example above:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable', { ... });
```

If you're just looking to get the content of the editor, you can just use the `editor.getContent()` helper method (documentation [here](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#getcontentindex)) and that will return the html content of the editor.  This will give you the `.innerHTML` of the editor element.

```
var x = editor.getContent();  // x is the innerHTML of the editor
```

If you're looking to be notified of any change to the editor (typing, pasting, formatting changes, etc.) you can subscribe the the `editableInput` custom event and be notified when those changes happen:

```
editor.subscribe('editableInput', function (eventObj, editable) {
    // You can get the content of the editor at this point multiple ways
    var x = editable.innerHTML; // editable is the editor <div> element that was changed
    var y = editor.getContent(); // getContent() returns the content of the editor as well
    x === y; // TRUE
});
```

If you're looking to grab the content of the editor when your publish button is clicked, you just need to keep a reference around of the editor:

```
$('#publish_article').click(function () {
    var x = editor.getContent();
    // The publish button has been clicked and you now have the content of the editor in x
});
```

I'm not sure what you were looking to do with the content once you got access to it, but hopefully the examples above should help you piece together the functionality you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I actually appreciate your code @Jason, it was helpful and you've given me extra tips but I did try before now and it did grab the whole `innerHTML` for me:

```
$("#publish_article").click(function() {
    editor.html()
});
```